# Height and Width of a view are always 0 ( getMeasuredHeight() and getHeight() both are not working )

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` inside a `LinearLayout` and child `linearlayout` have its `layout params` where `height` and `width` are defined  as

```
LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

now after view created i am  trying to get height of a view from `getHeight()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` but both methods returning **0** .   ?

```
  int heightofView=linearLayout.getHeight(); 
  int heightofview=linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
```

why both these methods are returning 0 height of a view ? when these methods return the actual result  ? how to get height of my created view ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code.

```
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
           int width = imageView.getWidth();
           int height = imageView.getHeight();
           //you can add your code here on what you want to do to the height and width you can pass it as parameter or make width and height a global variable
           imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Do as below -

```
linearLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int linearLayoutHeight = linearLayout.getHeight();
                Log.e("MS", "linearLayout Ht = " + linearLayoutHeight);
            }
        });
```